# ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer dos peticiones a la vez en un servicio en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, http

En mi servicio.service.ts me gustaría realizar dos peticiones a la vez. Lo que pretengo es hacer un httpClient de personas para obtener el id y posteriormente con ese id realizar otra petición pero no me funciona

```
 getDatos() {

    const URL = `${this.urlBase}/api/personas`; 
  
 return this.httpClient.get(URL, {})
    .pipe(
      map((response: any) =>{
       const personas_id= response.personas;//me devuelve el id
       const URL2 = `${this.urlBase}/api/datos/` + personas_id;
       return this.httpClient.get(URL2, {})
       .pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.datos)

      )
      }
      
       )
      

    )
```

}

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de `map` usa `switchMap`.

```
getDatos() {
    const URL = `${this.urlBase}/api/personas`;

    return this.httpClient.get(URL, {}).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => {
        const personas_id = response.personas; //me devuelve el id
        const URL2 = `${this.urlBase}/api/datos/` + personas_id;
        return this.httpClient
          .get(URL2)
          .pipe(map((response: any) => response.datos));
      })
    );
  }
```

[Referencia](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Answer (score 1):

**map** te funciona para manipular la respuesta del observable y transformarlo en otro valor diferente y lo que estas necesitando en este punto es transformar el observable a otro, por lo cual el operador que necesitas es **switchMap**

tu porción de código sería algo así:

```
getDatos() {
const URL = `${this.urlBase}/api/personas`;
return this.httpClient.get(URL, {}).pipe(
  switchMap((response: any) => {
    const personas_id = response.personas; //me devuelve el id
    const URL2 = `${this.urlBase}/api/datos/` + personas_id;
    return this.httpClient
      .get(URL2, {})
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.datos));
  })
);
}
```

Al realizar el llamado a la función *getDatos()* obtienes como resultado un observable de la petición de *${this.urlBase}/api/datos/*

[Documentación oficial de RXJS](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)